# How do I query a stored procedure in node-odbc/sybase?

Tags: node.js, odbc, sybase, node-odbc

After lots of google-fu, I figured out a way to query the ancient sybase database to start building a rest api for a mobile app I'm working on using node-odbc (https://github.com/markdirish/node-odbc/blob/master/README.md#callprocedurecatalog-schema-name-parameters-callback).

I have managed to successfully query with a select statement, but would prefer not to do that for security purposes.
when I try to use a stored procedure I'm getting a weird response. I need a sanity check here and figure out what I'm missing.

an example stored procedure I tried is a simple sp with one parameter to check for an email address using an account number (this is a fake sp of course, but formated the same way):

"DB"."spGetEmail"(@acctnum varchar(50) )

**the docs show this:**

const odbc = require('odbc');

odbc.connect(`${process.env.CONNECTION_STRING}`, (error, connection) => {
connection.callProcedure(null, null, 'MY_PROC', [undefined], (error, result) => {
if (error) { console.error(error) } // handle
// result contains an array of results, and has a `parameters` property to access parameters returned by the procedure.
console.log(result);
});
});

**I interpreted it to look like this:**

odbc.connect(${process.env.CONNECTION_STRING}, (error, connection) => {
connection.callProcedure(null, "DB", "spGetEmail", [123456], (error, result) => {
if (error) { console.error(error) } // handle
// result contains an array of results, and has a `parameters` property to access parameters returned by the procedure.
console.log(result);
});
});

**then I get this:**

> [Error: [odbc] The number of parameters the procedure expects and and
> the number of passed parameters is not equal] {   odbcErrors: [] }
> undefined Segmentation fault

seems straight forward, that I'm missing some parameters, but I KNOW that I'm not. The dang sp takes one parameter!

What am I missing here??

Comment: What exact Sybase DB do you mean?

Comment: sybase 16, SQL Anywhere 16 to be precise.

Comment: Did you try `sqlanywhere` package?

Comment: yup. it crashed before it installed giving the following error message:

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 4294967295
npm ERR! sqlanywhere@1.0.24 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlanywhere@1.0.24 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jasmine.logan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-14T19_39_17_409Z-debug.log

Comment: also tried the manual version where you npm install --global windows-build-tools as admin in powershell. It didn't crash, but didn't work out in the code either. 

Comment: was able to do a sql statement query after following these instructions, still not sure of the correct syntax for stored procedures. 
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sybaseiq-odbc-nodejs.rst

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
I'm not sure if the built in .callProcedure() method is broken or just not suited to Sybase16, but I found a way around it in case it's helpful to anyone in the future.
Instead of using the callProcedure() method, do this:

```
  odbc.connect(connectionString, (error, connection) => {

    let my_procedure = "exec spGetEmail @acct='12345678'"

    connection.query(my_procedure, (error, result) => {
        if (error) { console.error(error) }
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey @Jasmine Logan , Could you please tell me the format of your connection string? I am also in need of connecting to Sybase via NodeJS

Comment: @Jasmine Logan - Not sure how you could get OUT params from a sproc like this.